# Need partition size for Android BoardConfig.mk(without /proc/mtd)

Tags: android, size, block, partition, cyanogenmod

I'm building cm for my new device, and handling BoardConfig.mk.

The guide that I've found says I can get the PARTITION_SIZE by doing

> cat /proc/mtd.

However I've found that I don't have mtd, only have mounts, partitions or something.

This is part of what I found on recovery logs and partitions:

> /boot | /dev/block/mmcblk0p16 | Size: 13MB
>
> Current_File_System: emmc
>
> Fstab_File_System: emmc
>
> major  minor   #blocks name
>
> 179       16      13312 mmcblk0p16

But I don't know how to get the PARTITION_SIZE for BoardConfig.mk from these informations.(Calculating?, More info needed?)

Thank you. Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well established solution set.

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

If you need to pull partitions, you can also look here:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2450045

Comment: Thank you. I learned exact ways to show the matches of /dev/blocks+blocks+partition name. Plus, I was blind. In CM it described that partition size is typically blocks*1024.